# How do I include a data-extraction module into my python project?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently starting a kind of larger project in python and I am unsure about how to best structure it. Or to put it in different terms, how to build it in the most "pythonic" way. Let me try to explain the main functionality:

It is supposed to be a tool or toolset by which to extract data from different sources, at the moment mainly SQL-databases, in the future maybe also data from files stored on some network locations. It will probably consist of three main parts:

- A data model which will hold all the data extracted from files / SQL. This will be some combination of classes / instances thereof. No big deal here
- One or more scripts, which will control everything (Should the data be displayed? Outputted in another file? Which data exactly needs to be fetched? etc) Also pretty straightforward
- And some module/class (or multiple modules) which will handle the data extraction of data. This is where I struggle mainly

So for the actual questions:

- Should I place the classes of the data model and the "extractor" into one folder/package and access them from outside the package via my "control script"? Or should I place everything together?
- How should I build the "extractor"? I already tried three different approaches for a `SqlReader` module/class: I tried making it just a simple module, not a class, but I didn't really find a clean way on how and where to initialize it. (Sql-connection needs to be set up) I tried making it a class and creating one instance, but then I need to pass around this instance into the different classes of the data model, because each needs to be able to extract data. And I tried making it a static class (defining
  everything as a`@classmethod`) but again, I didn't like setting it up and it also kind of felt wrong.
- Should the main script "know" about the extractor-module? Or should it just interact with the data model itself? If not, again the question, where, when and how to initialize the `SqlReader`
- And last but not least, how do I make sure, I close the SQL-connection whenever my script ends? Meaning, even if it ends through an error. I am using `cx_oracle` by the way

I am happy about any hints / suggestions / answers etc. :)

Comment: Very nice question. Awesome work, very nice research done before posting/asking. I hope you find the insight you are looking for!

Answer (score 0):

For this project you will need the basic Data Science Toolkit: Pandas, Matplotlib, and maybe numpy. Also you will need SQLite3(built-in) or another SQL module to work with the databases.

Pandas: Used to extract, manipulate, analyze data.

Matplotlib: Visualize data, make human readable graphs for further data analyzation.

Numpy: Build fast, stable arrays of data that work much faster than python's lists.

Now, this is just a guideline, you will need to dig deeper in their documentation, then use what you need in your project.
Hope that this is what you were looking for!
Cheers